# Show names with 3 words only in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, function

I have a database with table contains information about employees in my company. 
I need a SQL statement to show all names whose have 3 parts like "haitham samey hegazy" and who less or more than 3 parts didn't shown in the condition result.
I try to use like operator but it doesn't work and my database is in Arabic language.

Thanks for helping...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show what you have tried. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming names are separated by a single space, you can get at least three parts using:

```
where name like '% % %'
```

You can get exactly three parts using:

```
where name like '% % %' and name not like '% % % %'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace to count the number of spaces:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(varcharColumn))) -
      LEN(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(varcharColumn)), ' ', '')) >= 2
```

This will return all the rows where there are at least 2 spaces inside the varcharColumn.

Comment: I can't understand these 

Comment: RTRIM and LTRIM removes the leading and following spaces, LEN returns the number of chars in the string, and REPLACE returns a string where every occurence of the second argument in the first argument is replaced with the third argument.